# How to use multiple statements inside do loop in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

**Problem**
Count the number occurrence in a list, they must be adjacent. Ex: `(a a b b c c a e)`, returns 
`( (a 2) (b 2) (c 2) (a 1) (e 1) )`.

I tried,

```
(define (loop lst) 
  (let ((i 1) (j 0))
    (do ()
      [(> j (- (length lst) 2))]
      (if (eq? (car lst) (cadr lst))
          (set! i (+ i 1))
          (display i)
      )
      (
         (set! lst (cdr lst))
         (set! j (+ j 1))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

When running, DrScheme complained

```
procedure application: expected procedure, given: #<void>; arguments were: #<void>
```

How can I use multiple statements inside an `if` or a `do` loop like this?

Thanks,

Comment: -1 My eyes! The goggles do nothing!

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: I don't get it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? That doesn't look like any code a sane Schemer would, or should, want to write.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: Forgive me! I'm very struggling to learn Scheme now. I was obsessed so much by traditional imperative language structure. I felt extremely uncomfortable using parentheses as code block. Honestly, I almost gave up!

Comment: Right, and that's why I just posted you a `fold`-based answer. Once you get the hang of `fold`, `map`, etc., you won't want to use imperative-style loops again. :-) (I just retracted my downvote, BTW. Thanks for explaining your task.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, you want to compute the run lengths! Guess what! Another problem for `fold`! :-P

```
(define (run-lengths lst)
  (fold-right (lambda (elem result)
                (if (and (pair? result)
                         (equal? elem (caar result)))
                    (cons (cons elem (+ (cdar result) 1)) (cdr result))
                    (cons (cons elem 1) result)))
              '() lst))
```

(My version returns the run lengths as dotted pairs, rather than lists of length 2.) Since you're using Racket, you can use `foldr` instead of `fold-right`; that way, you won't need to load SRFI 1.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: Now, you hurt my eyes. Thanks!

Comment: @Chan: Hahaha. Do your best to study how my function works, by reading up on how `foldr` works. It will enlighten you! :-)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: Well, I'm familiar with the meaning of fold. I read from wiki, it is similar to `std::accumulate` in C++. Still, the `()` was super annoying :(!

Comment: @Chan: It is exactly like `std::accumulate`. :-) One day, you'll get used to looking at the brackets (or rather, _not_ looking at them). :-)

Comment: @Chan: (Also, `map` is like `std::transform`, and `cons` is like `std::make_pair`, while we're on comparisons with C++.)

Comment: @Chan: Notice the difference in code structure, too. Lispers don't put "dangling" parenthesis on a line the same way C* language programmers tend to put curly braces on a line. This actually *increases* the readability of your code. For more info check out this lisp style guide: http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt

Comment: @Shaun: Thanks for the comments and the very helpful link. I'm really trying hard. Hope it will pay me back something.